# vmware window size for ubuntu CLI

Tags: windows-7, vmware, ubuntu-11.04

I want to maximize the window size (full screen) while working in ubuntu. I have tried using fullscreen option in vmware but failed.

vmware version = 3.1.4

guest os = ubuntu 11.04 (CLI) command line interface only.

host os = Windows 7 Professional, 32-bit , Service Pack 1.

any help please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We will have to edit grub configuration. Open a terminal and paste this:

1. `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
   Hit Enter. It will open grub preferences in Gedit.
2. Locate the line `# GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600` (resolution may be different).

You have to change the resolution to actual resolution of your screen, 
for example mine is 1240x1024. Next step is to uncomment this line (remove the # and and the empty space if is, so the letter G of the word GRUB will be the first letter in this line). After you are done, save the file and close.

3 . Now paste this line in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/00_header .
```

Hit Enter. It will open a text file with a lot of stuff. Use the search option at the top of the window to locate this line:

```
gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}
```

After you successfully find it, you will have to add this line: `set gfxpayload=keep` just under the `gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}`. Make it look like this:

```
set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}
set gfxpayload=keep
```

Now, save the file and close.

4 . In terminal paste:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Hit enter, it will generate new `grub.cfg` file so the changes you made will be saved.

Reboot and enjoy your new boot screen resolution.

In case you don't know what is your screen resolution

Go to System settings - Displays

From the link - https://askubuntu.com/questions/127851/change-boot-screen-resolution

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, future writing will not have such short forms. thanks for editing.

Comment: Thank you for the great reply, but this has stopped working for Ubuntu 22.10.

Answer (score 0):

From you main machine, start -> search -> "remote desktop connection" -> click on "remote desktop connection" -> Click "Options" Beside to "Connect Button" -> Display Tab - > Then increase Display Configuriton Size. If this will not work, try the same thing by closing remote desktop. But this will give you solution.